# Promise object results in different type with await/then

Tags: typescript

This code compiles

```js
import yargs from "yargs";

const parser = yargs(process.argv.slice(2)).
    usage("$0 [filename]").
    demandCommand(1);

async function main() {
    const argv = await parser.argv;
}
```

while this does not

```js
import yargs from "yargs";

const parser = yargs(process.argv.slice(2)).
    usage("$0 [filename]").
    demandCommand(1);

parser.argv.then(argv => {});
```

with compile errors

```
src/index.ts:13:1 - error TS18046: 'parser.argv.then' is of type 'unknown'.

13 parser.argv.then(argv => {});
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/index.ts:13:18 - error TS7006: Parameter 'argv' implicitly has an 'any' type.

13 parser.argv.then(argv => {});
                    ~~~~
```

My language server reports that type of `parser.argv` is

```js
(property) yargs.Argv<{}>.argv: {
    [x: string]: unknown;
    _: (string | number)[];
    $0: string;
} | Promise<{
    [x: string]: unknown;
    _: (string | number)[];
    $0: string;
}>
```

I thought `await`ing on promise object and `.then`ing on promise object would result in same type but it did not. Does `await`/`then` behave in different ways in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `parser.argv` is not a promise at runtime.

While you can `await` any value, you can only call `.then()` on a promise (or *then-able*, aka an object with a `then` method).

If you want to ensure a promise value, you can wrap it with [Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

```ts
Promise.resolve(parser.argv).then((argv) => {
  // ...
});
```